# Add data from multiple colums to one column in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

How to add multiple column's data into a single column in SQL Server?

I have columns like `Loc_BldgStreet, Loc_Area, Loc_City, Loc_State, Loc_Country` and I want to add them all into one single column (in view) to show them in gridview (asp.net) as in single column as full address to avoid very wide grid.

How to do it? I am using linq for binding grid from the location_view.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The + sign is what you use to concatinate strings in SQL.

```
col1 + col2 as Colname
```

If one of the columns happens to be numeric (i.e. int) then use convert or cast

```
col1 + convert(varchar(10), col2) as Colname
```

If one of the columns allows null, you'll need to use IsNull otherwise, the entire string will return null:

```
col1 + isnull(col2, '') as Colname
```

To create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS

SELECT col1, col2, col3 + col4 + col5 as NewColName
FROM dbo.MyTable
GO
```

You can also create a computed column and place your concatination there.  Computed columns can also use functions for things like running totals and such and do not require the extra view.

Comment: thnx Chris! this was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL 2012, you can build a single column using [CONCAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx).

Otherwise, use the '+' operand as the other answers have indicated.

Comment: I believe this will only work if they are using sql-server 2012

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select isnull(Loc_BldgStreet,'') +
       isnull(Loc_Area,'') +
       isnull(Loc_City,'') +
       isnull(Loc_State,'') + 
       isnull(Loc_Country,'')
from <your table>
```